# how to use an mdf in App_Data with shared hosting

Tags: sql-server, mdf, app-data, datadirectory

If I create a website that uses an mdf in App_Data with the connection string:

> `Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;`

what do I need to do to run the site in a shared hosting environment?  Do I need to copy the contents of my mdf to the main SQL Server engine of my host?  Is there a way to use the non-SQLExpress engine of my host and still keep my mdf in my App_Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mdf files will only work with SQL Server engines (Express or the full versions). The provider you use will need to provide access to a SQL Server engine. As Gortok said, a lot depends on the provider. See their documentation for the details.

Answer (score 2):

Your webhost should have documentation on this.  [Gearhost.com](http://gearhost.com) is my webhost, and they do.

If your webhost doesn't have documentation on this, email them and then find a new webhost.